# Find most used values in JSON file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, search

I have a JSON file set up as follows

```
"mediaPosts": [
  {
      "index": 0,
      "source": "Twitter",
      "post": "commodo cillum in ut aliquip ad commodo esse duis sunt pariatur nostrud quis quis magna non ipsum Lorem cupidatat laboris",
      "sentiment": "Positive",
      "date": "24/05/2014",
      "gender": "Male",
      "age": 30,
      "country": "Gabon"
  },....]
```

The file contains 4000 records.

What I would like to know is what would be the best way to find 5 countries that appear the most in this JSON file

The only way I can think to do this is the following:

1.Create a variable for every country in the world (This would mean the creation of a wopping 196 variables)

2.Loop through my JSON list

```
for (i = 0; i < postObject.mediaPosts.length; i++)
```

3. Check the country string value for each record and increase the count of the corresponding country variable

   if (postObject.mediaPosts[i].country == "Afghanistan") {afghanistan++;}
   else if (postObject.mediaPosts[i].country == "Albania") {albania++;}
4. Then find the 5 largest values amogst my country variables

However this process feels very cumbersome so I was wondering if there is a better way to do this>

Answer (score 2):

```
var countries = {};

for (i = 0; i < postObject.mediaPosts.length; i++) {
    var country = postObject.mediaPosts[i].country;
    countries[country] = countries[country] ? countries[country] + 1 : 1
}
```

then you will have an object (an associative array) of the countries as keys, and their count in the input object. Something like this:

```
countries = {
    "Afghanistan" : 5,
    "Albania" : 3,
    "Bulgaria" : 2,
    //... the other countries
}
```

From there you can loop over it and create pairs from it

```
var countryCountPairs = {};

for (country in countries) {
    countryCountPairs.push({country : country,  count : countries[country]});
}
```

Which will get you a data structure like this:

```
countryCountPairs = {
    { country : "Afghanistan",  count : 5 },
    { country : "Albania",  count : 3 },
    { country : "Bulgaria",  count : 2 },
    //... the other countries
}
```

And that is easily sortable:

```
countryCountPairs.sort(function(a, b) {
    // I think biggest value comes first with this, but you will have to test it. 
    return b.count - a.count;  
});
```

Which will give you a sorted version of the above.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! I will try implement it and see if this works for me